# Hudson can't execute SVN command "svn: undefined symbol"

Tags: java, linux, svn, hudson

I'm with a very strange problem.

Hudson was working fine at my Suse server with SVN 1.8 installed from *zypper*, but I needed to uninstall Subversion 1.8 and install the 1.7.5 version.

I tried to do it with *zypper*, but did't work, so I removed Subversion from the system (*zypper rm subversion*) and installed the desired version from a tar.bz2 file downloaded from the Apache official web site.

The installation wasn't simple because I needed to made a lot of little steps in the before finish. It was something like this http://clumsyfingers.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/installing-subversion-17-on-centos-55.html

Ok. Then the installation was finished and the SVN was recognized by the SO:

```
svn --version

svn, version 1.7.5 (r1336830)
     compiled Jul  2 2013, 18:16:17
Copyright (C) 2012 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people; see the NOTICE
file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
```

But after that Hudson stopped working!  When I try to run a build, the following error message are showed:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------      
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty    
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal  
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare (default-cli) on project 
project: Unable to check for local modifications Provider message: The svn command 
failed. Command output: svn: symbol lookup error: svn: undefined symbol: 
svn_pool_create_allocator

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)       
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)          
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)  
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)          
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)     
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)     
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)  
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)  
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:146)     
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:124)  
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)   
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:107)    
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:41)     
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:276)  
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)  
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)   
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by: 
    org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Unable to check for local modifications 
    Provider message: The svn command failed. Command output: svn: symbol lookup error: 
    svn: undefined symbol: svn_pool_create_allocator

    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:285)  
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:232)     
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)  
    ... 27 more Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.scm.ReleaseScmCommandException: Unable to check for local modifications Provider message: The svn command failed. 
    Command output: svn: symbol lookup error: svn: undefined symbol: svn_pool_create_allocator

    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.ScmCheckModificationsPhase.execute(ScmCheckModificationsPhase.java:137)    
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)    
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)    
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)    
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)    
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:277)  
    ... 30 more channel stopped Finished: FAILURE
```

I have no idea about what I should do now.

May you help me, please?
If you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks a lot for the attention!